# Angular Material Table - pre-sorting two columns at startup, one based on the other

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material table of about eight columns on which I am trying to do a custom sort. When the table is brought up, I want the table to be initially sorted based on a column with dates in a descending order. This I have achieved. Here is the code I am using for that:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

getDisbursementsDetails() {
    this.claimDetailsService.getDisbursements(this.claimNumber).subscribe(
      disbursements => {
        let disbursementsDetails = this.buildDisbursements(disbursements);
        this.disbursementsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(disbursementsDetails);
        this.disbursementsDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.disbursementsDataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.applySorting(this.disbursementsDataSource);
        this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{id: 'issueDate', start: 'desc'});
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.disbursementsDetailsSpinner = false;
        this.errorHandling(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Just to note, the applySorting method is not relevant to this issue. All it does is format the dates and dollar amounts in different columns so that when they are sorted they sort properly.

The line that causes the column labeled Issue Date to be pre-sorted when the table appears is this:

```
this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{id: 'issueDate', start: 'desc'});
```

Here is what I'm trying to do. I want a second column to be pre-sorted also based on the first pre-sorted column. The second column consists of document numbers. The sorting would be descending. The way it would work is that if the first column had a number of dates that are the same, then for those dates the document numbers would be sorted in descending order.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try to carry out a classic ordering with the type method, when the first sea field equals the second

```
let sortedArray: TypeObject[] = this.disbursementsDetails.data.sort((p1, p2) =>{
   if(p1.field1 > p1.field1){ 
        return 1;
   } else if(p1.field1< p2.field1){
        return -1;
   } else if(p1.field2 > p1.field2){
        return 1;
   } else if(p1.field2< p2.field2){
        return -1;
   }else {
        return 0;
   } 
});

this.disbursementsDetails.data = sortedArray;
```